# Apple like dropdown control

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there any standard way to create apple like drop down?
[image]

Comment: Apple like drop down control ? Please add more information

Answer (score -1):

There is no dropdown in IOS like there is in Android. To make, I recon you can user UITableView; to attain something like your picture, you can eliminate the cell separator, cancel the bounces  property of the tableView

Comment: This question is tagged "cocoa", not "cocoa-touch" or "ios".